# Why is my embedded video not being responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have this script to embed video from youtube. The video plays well but, i am not being able to set width in % to make the video responsive. How can it be done?

```
<div  class="video-container" id="VideoPlayer"></div> 

 <script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
     <script>
                 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                  var player;
                  player = new YT.Player('VideoPlayer', {
                    videoId: 'yusGUGTVAyw', // YouTube Video ID
                    width: 560,               // Player width (in px)
                    height: 400,              // Player height (in px)
                    playerVars: {
                      autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
                      controls: 1,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
                      showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
                      modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
                      loop: 5,            // Run the video in a loop
                      fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
                      cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
                      iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
                      autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
                    },
                    events: {
                      onReady: function(e) {
                        e.target.mute();
                      }
                    }
                  });
                 }

   </script>
```

and this css:

```
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

But, the video is not being responsive. seems like the css is not taking effect.What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the class "video-container"from the div the javascript is targeting and put it in a div like this

```
<div class="video-container">
<div  class="" id="VideoPlayer"></div> 
</div>
```

See below

```css
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px; 
  height: 0; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
<div  class="" id="VideoPlayer"></div> 
</div>
 <script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
     <script>
                 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                  var player;
                  player = new YT.Player('VideoPlayer', {
                    videoId: 'yusGUGTVAyw', // YouTube Video ID
                    width: 560,               // Player width (in px)
                    height: 400,              // Player height (in px)
                    playerVars: {
                      autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
                      controls: 1,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
                      showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
                      modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
                      loop: 5,            // Run the video in a loop
                      fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
                      cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
                      iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
                      autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
                    },
                    events: {
                      onReady: function(e) {
                        e.target.mute();
                      }
                    }
                  });
                 }

   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should place the div element that contains the video in a separate container for the positioning on your page.
Then you can modify the size of the video container using css.

Try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g04fxeLp/1/)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div  class="video-container" id="VideoPlayer"></div> 
</div>
```

```js
 <script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
     <script>
                 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                  var player;
                  player = new YT.Player('VideoPlayer', {
                    videoId: 'yusGUGTVAyw', // YouTube Video ID
                    playerVars: {
                      autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
                      controls: 1,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
                      showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
                      modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
                      loop: 5,            // Run the video in a loop
                      fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
                      cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
                      iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
                      autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
                    },
                    events: {
                      onReady: function(e) {
                        e.target.mute();
                      }
                    }
                  });
                 }

   </script>
```

By the way, you can also remove the fixed size in the youtube iframe api call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried answers on this URL?

[Why is my embedded video not being responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43578836/why-is-my-embedded-video-not-being-responsive/43578979#43578979)

I think there is answer for you, because question title is same.

Good luck.

UPDATE:

Oh, you have asked this 2 (or more) times, because the link is for question by you (Steve).

My bad.

I think you have the right answer.
Maybe you can delete this question or the another (you can think it yourself do you delete or not).